# color image in grub

Tags: grub2

I'm using grub customizer to put a background image in grub;
when I use an image that is basically grey and black, everything works perfectly; when I use a coloured image, it is ignored; both images have the same size and are both rgb mode;

is there a particular format the image should have?

Comment: I'd like to know too, I haven't been able to get any images to work with grub (grub2 actually) with the `GRUB_BACKGROUND=` line, even with the boot menu images from Ubuntu & Mint live iso's. Never tried a B&W image, but if it worked that raises more questions

Comment: @Xen2050 See my answer for some tips on image format. The wiki page I linked to has more detailed info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are specific requirements that Grub background images must meet in order to work properly.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays :

> ### Choosing a GRUB 2 Background Image
>
> GRUB 2 can use PNG, JPG/JPEG and TGA images for the background. The image must meet the following specifications:
>
> - JPG/JPEG images must be 8-bit (256 color). Else you will get errors saying "Too many Huffman tables". Since most of the time you will not want to limit yourself to 256 colors (which is totally yesteryear) you will probably find PNG much preferable.
> - Images should be non-indexed, RGB.
> - The GIMP image editor is one application which can edit images to conform to the GRUB 2 standards. Use the Image > Mode menu options to set the properties to RGB and ensure the mode is not set to Indexed.

Comment: I've solved saving the background image I was trying to use as .tga with gimp; that format worked like a charm; don't know exactly why but the .png version was not working even if it is officially supported